# Enter a user response through code

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm currently working on Microsoft Botframework Node.js SDK.

I was wondering if there was a way to hard code a user response for a prompt through the code?

The scenario is to add/ remove people to the meeting. The dialog contains 2 waterfall functions. The first is used to handle card actions, and display the default prompt to enter a username to search for. The second function searches for the username and displays the results in a carousel. Selecting a user from the card adds the person to the meeting (handled in first waterfall function).

Once a user is added to the meeting, the first waterfall function displays the currently added people in the meeting with the option to remove, followed by the default prompt to search users. Since it expects a prompt response, the "remove" actions causes a break and the bot's response is: "I didn't understand. Please try again.".

So is it possible to hard code a null user response through the code when the "remove" action is triggered? Or is there any other way to bypass a prompt without any input from the user's end?

Comment: Could you please share some code snippet and screenshot? The problem is unclear.

Comment: I'm unable to share the actual code. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/UjPi3CPw) a algorithm of sorts, of what the functions are doing.